# Select one checkbox from 2 column checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, selection

I have 2 columns of checkboxes in a gridview, where the header also contains a checkbox.
 If i select the header checkbox, it will check all corresponding checkboxes in its colomn.
Now, what I want to happen is if I select column 1 checkbox, column 2 checkboxes should get unchecked and vice-versa.  My code is as below help would be appreciated:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #form1
        {
            height: 138px;
            width: 509px;
        }
    </style>
     <script type="text/javascript" >
        function SelectAll(id)
        {
             // alert(id); 
             // GridView_ctl01_cbSelectAll 
            //get reference of GridView control
            var cell; 
            var cellnext;

            if(id =='GridView_ctl01_cbSelectAll')

            {
            var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView.ClientID %>");
            //variable to contain the cell of the grid


            if (grid.rows.length > 0)
            {
                //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
                for (i=1; i<grid.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    //get the reference of first column
                    cell = grid.rows[i].cells[1];

                    //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
                    for (j=0; j<cell.childNodes.length; j++)
                    {           
                        //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
                        if (cell.childNodes[j].type =="checkbox")
                        {
                        //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the

                            cell.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;


                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            }

            else
            {

            //alert("yes");
             var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView.ClientID %>");
            //variable to contain the cell of the grid


            if (grid.rows.length > 0)
            {
                //loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
                for (i=1; i<grid.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    //get the reference of first column
                    cellnext = grid.rows[i].cells[2];

                    //loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
                    for (j=0; j<cellnext.childNodes.length; j++)
                    {           
                        //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
                        if (cellnext.childNodes[j].type =="checkbox")
                        {
                        //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the grid


                           cellnext.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;


                        }
                    }





                }


            }

            }
            }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
 <form runat ="server" id="form1">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    Width="100%" Visible="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="False" GridLines="none" ShowHeader="true"
                    SelectedRowStyle-Wrap="false">

                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <strong>Name</strong>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:Label runat="server" class="ms-vb" ID="lblemployees" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemStyle Width="35%" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <strong>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="return SelectAll(this.id);" AutoPostBack="false" />
                                    Sleep (6 Hours)  
                                </strong>

                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                       <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemStyle Width="50%" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <strong>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll1" runat="server" onclick="return SelectAll(this.id);" AutoPostBack="false" />
                                    Wake
                                </strong>

                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect1" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
</form>
    <p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And its source code is:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim sqlconn As SqlConnection
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strsql As String

        Dim s As String = "whatever it may be "
        sqlconn = New SqlConnection(s)

        Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
        Dim sqlAdp As SqlDataAdapter

        sqlconn.Open()
        strsql = "select name from tab_name"
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlconn
        sqlCmd.CommandText = strsql
        sqlAdp = New SqlDataAdapter()
        sqlAdp.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
        Dim DS As New DataSet()
        sqlAdp.Fill(DS, "Return")
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt = DS.Tables(0)
        sqlCmd.Dispose()
        sqlconn.Close()
        GridView.DataSource = dt
        GridView.DataBind()

    End Sub


    'Protected Sub GridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView.RowDataBound
    '    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header Then
    '        'Find the checkbox control in header and add an attribute
    '        DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll"), CheckBox).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SelectAll('" + DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbSelectAll"), CheckBox).ClientID & "')")
    '    End If
    'End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I came up with for this:

```
function SelectAll(id)
{
    //get reference of GridView control
    var grid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView.ClientID %>");
    if (grid.rows.length > 0)
    {
        var onIndex;
        var offIndex;

        // First, assume that the item is checked
        if (id == 'GridView_ctl01_cbSelectAll') {
            // Assuming col1 is checked, set the onindex to 1 and of to 2
            onIndex = 1;
            offIndex = 2;
        } else {
            onIndex = 2;
            offIndex = 1;
        }

        // If the column is not checked, swap the indexes.
        if (!document.getElementById(id).checked) {
            var tempIndex;
            tempIndex = onIndex;
            onIndex = offIndex;
            offIndex = tempindex;
        }

        // loop starts from 1. rows[0] points to the header.
        for (var i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = grid.rows[i];
            SetCellCheckBox(row.cells[onIndex], true);
            SetCellCheckBox(row.cells[offIndex], false);
        }
    }

    function SetCellCheckBox(cell, value) {

        // loop according to the number of childNodes in the cell
        for (var j = 0; j < cell.childNodes.length; j++) {
            //if childNode type is CheckBox                 
            if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {
                //assign the status of the Select All checkbox to the cell checkbox within the
                cell.childNodes[j].checked = value;
                // Bail once we have found the checkbox
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well thanx for  th reply i have voted up but i also  want it for the each checkbox also this is for the coloumn if i want no two chck box can be check  at same  time in different column how can i do  that

Comment: @RaghavChopra: Should be pretty straightforward; you need an event handler that is fired when the user clicks the checkbox in the column, then you can use all of the code above except the loop. You only need to figure out which row the checkbox is on that was clicked.

Comment: @compentent can u please provide me the code because i m an new  to the .net so kinda confused can u please  provide me with the codde

Comment: ur code has a bug when i check one coulm all get  checked bt when i  check the other column all the checkboxes uncheck themselves and get checkes on the column which i checked but its main  check box is still checked in 1st column  how to resolve dat ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be to your help. I did solve it with jQuery. You can download the library here: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Here is my suggestion:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" Width="100%">
        <Columns>             
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>                      
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick="CheckAll(this,0);" />   
            </HeaderTemplate>                  
            <ItemTemplate>                       
                <input type="checkbox" class="dummychkstyle" id="chkSelect" runat="server" />                                   
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>                      
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll2" runat="server" onclick="CheckAll(this,1);" />   
            </HeaderTemplate>                  
            <ItemTemplate>                       
                <input type="checkbox" class="dummychkstyle2" id="chkSelect2" runat="server" />                                   
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>    
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CheckAll(selectChk, index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                CheckCheckboxes(".dummychkstyle", ".dummychkstyle2", $(selectChk).attr('checked'));
            }
            else {
                CheckCheckboxes(".dummychkstyle2", ".dummychkstyle", $(selectChk).attr('checked'));
            }
        }
        function CheckCheckboxes(column1Class, column2Class, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                $(column1Class).attr('checked', true);
                $(column2Class).attr('checked', false);
            }
            else {
                $(column1Class).attr('checked', false);
                $(column2Class).attr('checked', true);
            }
        } 
    </script>
```